# PHP Mail_mime adding backward slash in the content

Tags: php, pear, mail-mime

I am upgrading my PHP code from 5.2 to 7.3.

For creating email mime , I have using the PEAR library Mail_mime (https://github.com/pear/Mail_Mime).

After integrating the latest version, I am facing a strange issue where the backward slash
(\) is getting added randomly.

eg:

```
From: "George B@@Z"<georgeb@cort.org.au> is getting changed to 
From: "\"George" B@@Z"<georgeb@cort.org.au>

"Abel Thomas" <abel@mail.com> is getting changed to
 "Abel\ Thomas" <abel@mail.com>
```

This did not happen in the older version of the library.

Any lead to the possible solution is appreciated.

Comment: For 1st issue, the fix is committed in the official library i.e https://github.com/pear/Mail_Mime

Comment: Show the minimal code to reproduce that issue.